# Is it the right way to use relationship "one-to-one" to store tokens in MySQL db?

Tags: mysql, database

I have table `users` and I need to store temporal tokens in database. What is the right way to do this if they must be associated with field `email` in `users` table?
[image: Like this correct?]

*Is is correct?* It was based on the fact that tokens are not main user data and this is logical (use another table). They are storing 10 mins.

Comment: For a one-to-one relation `email` should be unique in both tables. You might also use `user_id` instead.

Comment: Setup UNIQUE KEY on email column in users table.